# Animating a surf plot

Tags: matlab, animation, matlab-figure

I've been tasked with animating a 3d helical flux tube in Matlab and I'm unsure of how to do so.

The only animation experience I've had was for plotting the 2d trajectories of 9 solar system planetary orbits, for which I used the following code (where z was a 27 column matrix whose columns were ordered in the sequence x,y,z 9 times as to represent 9 planets)

```
% Plot 9 empty plots
p = plot3(nan(9), nan(9), nan(9));

for k = 1:size(z, 1)
    % Update all of the plot objects at once
    set(p, {'XData'}, num2cell(z(1:k, 1:3:25), 1).', ...
           {'YData'}, num2cell(z(1:k, 2:3:26), 1).', ...
           {'ZData'}, num2cell(z(1:k, 3:3:27), 1).')
    drawnow
end
```

So, intuitively, I have tried to adapt this for the helical flux tube that I have as follows (where x, y and z are 21 x 301 matrices and so I assume that at each time step I must surf the rows of x,y and z accordingly up to the required time step):

```
p = surf(nan(21,301), nan(21,301), nan(21,301));

for k = 1:size(x,1)
    % Update all of the plot objects at once
    set(p, {'XData'}, num2cell(x(1:k, :), [1 301]), ...
           {'YData'}, num2cell(y(1:k, :), [1 301]), ...
           {'ZData'}, num2cell(z(1:k, :), [1 301]))
    drawnow
end
```

However, doing this i keep getting the error

```
Error using matlab.graphics.chart.primitive.Surface/set
Size mismatch in Param Cell / Value Cell pair.
```

I know I've probably made a silly mistake somewhere, but can anyone help? Or if I'm completely going about this the wrong way could anybody let me know?!

(NB If it helps, in the original script to plot the helical flux tube, the code is:)

```
surf(x,y,z,'facecolor', Colour, 'edgecolor',EdgeColour,...
    'facelighting','gouraud')
```

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure I get what you want but you could try:

```
for k = 1:size(x,1)
    surf(num2cell(x(1:k, :) ,num2cell(y(1:k, :), num2cell(z(1:k, :);
    M(i)=getframe;
end
```

And the display the it as a movie afterwards by:

```
numberofrepitions=3 % as often as you want to have it play in a row
movie(M,numberofrepetitions)
```

Maybe easier displayed on some random data as you didnt provide any:

```
x=[1 2 3; 2 3 4; 3 4 5];
y=[19 17 15; 13 11 9; 7 5 3];
z=[1 1 2; 2 1 1; 3 3 3];

for i=1:10
    surf(x,y,z);

    M(i)=getframe;
    x=x+10;
    y=y+20;
    z=z+25;
end 
movie(M,3)
```

The form of the created plot doesnt change but you can see the axis moving, so I guess it would work that way also for a varying form of your surface triangulation.

Comment: Sorry if I weren't clear, I want an animation showing the flux tube growing over time, so showing how it rises from the surface (its base point)

Comment: If I run what you said above, I get an error since p is not defined

Comment: Sorry, dont have matlab on the computer I am at atm, so I cant test, try this again ... you can add the variable names later ( I guess this question is more about the animation)

Comment: @R Thompson, check again I edited it with a little example - I hope this is what you were looking for

Answer (score 0):

You are getting that error because the following command *only creates one `surf` object*

```
p = surf(nan(21,301), nan(21,301), nan(21,301));

numel(p)
%   1
```

If that's what you want, then you don't want to use the `'{XData}'` notation but just the plain `'XData'`, etc.

However, if you *do* want to create multiple `surf` objects, you will want to do it within a loop. *Then* you should be able update them the way that you'd like.

Comment: Okay this runs fine without error but only reveals another question!! I guess what I previously asked for was incorrect. Using your correction shows the building of the flux tube around a 2d helix. I guess what I really wanted was to show say, what was originally a circle at the base point, and following this through time, so that we can see how the flux tube twists and rises over time. If that makes sense??

Comment: @RThompson How many `surf` objects were you hoping to create?

Comment: Just one helical flux tube, I think I may know where I've gone wrong I will just readdress the code quickly

Comment: @RThompson Yea I don't know what you mean by flux tube so you're going to have to add some code and/or data. Really though, that is beyond the scope of this particular question because this question was about what was causing your error.

Comment: Sorry I know it's very vague, the master script calls in 3 other function scripts hence why I didn't want to post it all here! I have figured it out though, all I needed to do was have x(: 1:k) etc instead of x(1:k :) and let k run from 1 to the number of columns rather than the number of rows and I got the desired animation!

Comment: @RThompson Ok well that seems like a very trivial modification of the code that we've provided here in the answer. Your initial question seems to have been answered so consider marking a solution.

Answer (score 0):

This code obtained the desired animation

```
p = surf(nan(21,301), nan(21,301), nan(21,301));

 for k = 1:301
     % Update all of the plot objects at once
     set(p, 'XData', x(:, 1:k), ...
            'YData', y(:, 1:k), ...
            'ZData', z(:, 1:k))

        drawnow
 end
```

So from the initial circle at the base point, the animation then shows the tube that forms as this initial circle rises (and twists) through time.

We no longer need the {} around the 'XData' etc since we are only needing the surf of one object, rather than the 9 before.

Thank you for all the help getting to this answer!